# UX, user interface and user interface elements and style/theming

Tags: windows, android, linux, ios, macos

I was wondering whether there are any window managers, on some, or, whatever, system, that may allow users to set elements from textures from pictures, partial pictures, or modified elements, of body, parts (and use them in clickable areas of backgrounds, frame elements (such as frame, buttons), and stuff like that.

You could do the same with cipria and makeup.

And you could have sparkles, corresponding, to whatever items you may use, when, you carry out whatever sorts of work it is, may it be tools...

How can you customize a user interface, with the power of something like Illustrator, Photoshop, Gimp, or Inkscape.

I don't know whether it is a good idea. I thought of it, because, presumably, user interface and user interface elements, ought to show, more, stuff (than, ?what they show)

I don't know if by drawing my skin on the phone, I might, want to hug it more.

You could have something suggestive of what someone looked, or how someone looked.

But I could draw other stuff in the background, or as user interface elements.

Thanks.